# How to get the selected items for DataTable in ipyvuetify

Tags: python, vuetify.js, jupyter, ipyvuetify

I'm using `ipyvuetify` and I still have some problems in understanding what `v_model`stands for.

What I need is a table with selectable rows and a button that reads selected lines and return them when clicked. I tried the following code.

```
import ipyvuetify as v

headers = [
    {"text": "Name", "value": "name"},
    {"text": "Age", "value": "age"}
]
items = [
    {'name': 'Henri', 'age': 12},
    {'name': 'Etienne', 'age': 30},
    {'name': 'Matthieu', 'age': 40}
]

table = v.DataTable(
    v_model=[],
    show_select=True, 
    item_key = 'name', 
    headers=headers, 
    items=items,
)

show_selected_btn = v.Btn(color="primary",children=["Show selected"])

card_text = v.CardText(children = ['text'])
card = v.Card(children=[card_text])

def on_click(widget, event, data):
    card_text.children = table.v_model

show_selected_btn.on_event('click', on_click)

v.Layout(
    column=True,
    children=[table, show_selected_btn, card]
)
```

My problem is that, as a Vue.js point of view, I understood the `v_model` as a global JS variable that was possible to access at any moment, but it seems it's also linked to an object (the table here). I then tried `table.v_model` but that does not work.

I need to know what to place instead of `v_model=[]` and `table.v_model` and why. The ipyvuetify doc is light on that subjetc.

A last question : how to initialize a selected row? Select all rows at startup? Does that go to the `v_model` attribute also?

Regards.

Comment: Please answer to this question crucial for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to change the value of v_model from:

```
v_model=[]
```

to

```
v_model='selected'
```

Then `table.v_model` will output the selected items.

Answer (score 0):

`v_model=[]` should work fine as you have done it. But, when assigning the `v_model` output to the card text, you just need to change the data type from a list of dictionaries to a string.

```py
def on_click(widget, event, data):
    card_text.children = str(table.v_model)
```

To select rows programmatically, you need to assign a list of dictionaries to the v_model. e.g.

```py
table.v_model = [{'name': 'Etienne', 'age': 30}]
```

[image]